# Change FOCUS from edit text field to check box, radio button, drop down for dynamic form in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am generating dynamic form in one of my android app.

I am having a problem to move from Edit Text to Check box using the "next" key in android soft keyboard.

The following line of code

```
editView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

is working fine for Edit text field.

I can move from Edit Text field to another Edit Text but not from Edit Text to Check box or Radio button or Drop down?

But it is not working for Check box or Radio button or Dropdown fields? 
checkBoxView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);

I am taking about "tab" functionality for android input form.

Any ideas how this can be done for android dynamic input form?

Thanks in advance.